# Enable assertions in Java Shell

Tags: java, java-9

```
C:\Users\Malvolio>jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> assert(false)

jshell>
```

How can I make the Java Shell throw an AssertionError when an assert fails?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start it with the command option:

```
jshell -R -ea
```

[image]

Comment: What mean `-R -ea`?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich `jshell -- help` for `-R` optional, while `-ea` is "enable assertions"